# MVC4 routing weirdness

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this ActionLink in one of my views

```
Html.ActionLink(pop.PopName, "ShowAllEncounters", "Encounter", new {popId = pop.populationID })
```

I am thinking that will take me to the correct route...
But I instead go to this route...

```
http://localhost:19283/Population/ShowAllEncounters?Length=9
```

The route should be

```
http://localhost:19283/Encounter/ShowAllEncounters?Length=9
```

I looked in my global.asax file and everything seems normal... I didn't change the default route by any means except to set the default opening page...

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Population", action = "PopulationInfo", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

Which is what i expected... Which is similar to an MVC3 route that I had.  Am I doing something funky with my routes?  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're calling the wrong method overload:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText,
    string actionName,
    Object routeValues,
    Object htmlAttributes
)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492124.aspx

**Instead**, try calling this overload:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText,
    string actionName,
    string controllerName,
    Object routeValues,
    Object htmlAttributes
)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504972.aspx

---

To call the proper overload use something akin to the following:

```
Html.ActionLink(pop.PopName,
                "ShowAllEncounters",
                "Encounter",
                null,
                new {popId = pop.populationID })
```

Comment: I believe it may be the other way around (for the last two parameeters) but I believe you have answered my question.
Also, I am writing out the string twice, and I can't seem to figure out why?

Answer (score 0):

Your code

```
Html.ActionLink(pop.PopName, "ShowAllEncounters", "Encounter", new {popId = pop.populationID })
```

Should be

```
Html.ActionLink(pop.PopName, "ShowAllEncounters", new {controller="Encounter"}, new {popId = pop.populationID })
```